# body is smaller than html

Tags: html, css

So, I have a html document, The BODY of the document is smaller than the HTML tag.

| Colors: | Element |
| --- | --- |
| Purple | Div inside the body |
| Green | Body |
| Orange | HTML |

| Libraries: |
| --- |
| water.css |

Code:

```css
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
* {
    border:1px solid red;
}
#app,body,html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#app {background:purple;}
body {background:green;}
html {background:orange;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css@2/out/water.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

What I get:

[image: WIG]

Comment: The width is set from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css

Comment: I know that, Im just trying to find out what CSS attribute sets it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Debugging Steps:**

You need to learn to use the Developer Tools in your browser. In Chrome, do the following:

1. Right-click on the purple element
2. Select "inspect"
3. Scroll to the bottom of the "Styles" pane.

You will see the layout showing you the width and height of the content as well as margins, borders, padding, etc. You will see that the content area is set to be 800px. If you also select the "body" element in the `Elements` pane you will see that the body is set for a max-width of 800px. If you search your linked CSS file (water.css) for `800` you will also see that it has a max-width of 800px set. If you do not want it to be 800px, you need to change it or override it.

**Order of Precedence:**

Also, just in case you were not aware, when you have conflicting styles, whichever style is last in your code takes precedence. So, if you have the link to water.css file first (with max-width: 800px) and then after that in your own CSS you override with max-width: 100%, yours will take precedence. If on the other hand, you have your own styles first and the water.css second, the water.css styles will take precedence.

Comment: Thanks! (I know how to use DEVTools, also I use firefox because I don't prefer google. They have too much control over us anyways.) I wasn't thinking of max-width!

Comment: I wasn't thinking of max-width either. But the Developer Tools make it clear that max-width was being used here. That's the only way that I found out was by using Developer Tools. If you knew how to use them you should have looked there first rather than posting a question here. I'm not trying to belittle you here, I'm just a bit confused as to why you wouldn't use them if you know how. That should almost always be your first place of checking whenever you encounter problems like this.

Comment: I did. I just didn't see a conflict with them. Also - I always put libraries first and my code last. so I can override libraries.

Comment: @Elijah629 There was no conflict as max-width was only used one time. I would argue that you probably do not know how to use the Developer Tools as much as you claim. Just by using Developer Tools you should have instantly been able to see immediately that the property max-width was set to 800px on the body. There were only a few properties set on the body so it's not like you would have had to scroll through hundreds of properties. You also should have been able to see from the `box diagram` that it was set to a width of 800px.